# find source code matched with machine address

Tags: c#, crash-dumps

I'm debugging a crash dump and I am clear at which address the process crashes. The source code is written in C#. My question is any quick way to find the matched source code related to the crash address?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding .pdb file available ? If you do, there should be some way of matching the address to a source code line.

Comment: Sure I have the PDB and a related symbol server. Which command should be used in Windbg to find related source code related to a specific address? I am not sure whether after JIT in runtime, Windbg still could find the original C# source code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any decent IDE that includes a debugger will do this automatically.  Otherwise, you typically need to build your project with debugging information (debug symbols) enabled (which isn't recommended for production, as it makes your program bigger and easier to reverse engineer), and debugger commands like where or trace will list the program lines you're at.

Comment: Thanks Lee B, I am debugging a crash dump. Could you show me how to find related line of source code in this case? Your reply is more about how to find during debugging a process other than debugging a dump?

Comment: BTW: in Visual Studio any ways to setup symbol path? I previously only setup symbol path in Windbg, not in Visual Studio before.

Comment: Ah, apologies.  For crash dumps, it's really down to the debugger in question, and its manual.  However, the basic idea is that you just load the debugger, and choose (or type) the command to load the dump.  It should just find the code from there.  If not, you may also need to specify a source dir.

Comment: Basic ("pdb-only") symbols will not impact your executable code, and you don't have to distribute them. (Full debug symbols are a different matter.)

Comment: I setup symbol path (where PDB is), so you mean it is not enough and I need to setup source code path?

Comment: Symbol path in vS: Tools | Options | Debugger | Symbols.

Comment: Richard, I have setup PDB path correctly in symbol path, do I still need to setup source path? If yes, after setup, which command should be used to display related C# source code?

Comment: Thanks Richard, but how to setup source path in VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

You need the symbol files (.pdb) from the build.

Also enable use of MS' symbol server so VS and WinDBG will automatically get the correct symbol files.

Comment: in Visual Studio any ways to setup symbol path? I previously only setup symbol path in Windbg, not in Visual Studio before.

Comment: Symbol path setting is my Windbg is setup correctly, and I know the machine address, which command should be used to display the related source code? :-)

Answer (score 0):

[this blog](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog) is a mine of useful information on crash dump analysis.

Here's where it starts on debugging a [managed app's crash dump](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2007/07/20/crash-dump-analysis-patterns-part-17/) it is worth noting that it refers back to previous articles and assumes you have read and understood them. It also assumes you a slightly familiar with Son of Strike, an incredibly useful but somewhat arcane debugging extension for working with managed code.

Comment: I stuied and the information is very helpful. But I can not find how to find related managed source code related to a specific machine address. Any ideas or comments?

Comment: The managed source code should not be the one causing the crash (barring a JIT bug) You should have a partially completed stack frame on the basis of what you ahve already. this must be added to with further symbols as available (say MS public ones) but ultimately the functions at the...

Comment: ...top of the stack may be third party dlls to which you have no symbols... at least you then have an idea whoose code misbehaved

Comment: What do you mean "The managed source code should not be the one causing the crash"? From analyze -v it is in my own managed method and the exception is NullReferenceException. So, I suspect somehting wrong (e.g. reference a NULL) pointer in my code. And I want to find it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah right - a null reference exception shouldn't trigger a crash dump (unless you do it yourself in code) just a stack trace...
Just include the pdb files and when the error happens you will get the exact line number